Pronunciation of sentence final 的
I have heard the character 的 pronounced similar to ‘deh’ as opposed to the standard ‘duh/də (with the schwa)’. It seems to only occur with sentence final 的, and potentially with speakers from the north. Is this a genuine phenomenon or am I mishearing?

Could it be a combination of 的 and a sentence-final particle like 欸?

This is OP. Thanks all for the help thus far. I’ve found a clip of this pronunciation on Xiaohongshu (http://xhslink.com/a/TCpnrTuEBSd1) in the form of “我是东北的”. I’m fairly sure this is just standard usage of 的. It is certainly 的, and not 得 or 地. Tuo’s answer makes sense to me (apologies I am not able to comment as I insufficient reputation). I would appreciate if someone could confirm based on the clip too?

Ref:
https://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail/?title=%E7%9A%84
And press the speaker/play icon to hear it's pronounce by yourself.
... ~~ Remember to turn on your speaker ~~
There's only 3 different pronounces of 的

ㄉㄧˋ dì
ㄉㄧˊ dí
ㄉㄜ˙ de

If you are looking for the sound ㄉㄟˇ - děi, it should be :
https://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail?title=%E5%BE%97

In my experience 的 can be spoken by 东北口音 in exaggeration, like 的一 with extra yee in the end as what you heard; or 滴欸 with an extra yee in the middle. video material.
Your provided example belongs to northeast accent 东北话/东北方言. It sounds different from Mandarin, which also derives from northen accent.

我的 发音是 wo de，这里的的发音是de
的确 发音是 di que，这里的的发音是di
如果你需要其他关于的的发音，请提供例子。

你沒有回答OP的問題吧————

@JohnFrazer 我回答了啊，每个人的标准不一样，不知道你对原问题有什么看法，欢迎写出你的答案。
